# How do I access/read the metadata from my Opensea NFT purchase?

Tags: meta-data

I have recently purchased an NFT on Opensea:

https://opensea.io/assets/0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e/35392070563509681805150427162397186746015806770332227833352734069616516530177

I am keen to explore the Metadata - in particular extracting the image URL from the Metadata (which I believe is stored on Googles cloud platform).

If I view the contract (https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcf4a0a69f727380f9716fbe243f0a4b63da5bd9e3933cdbb6ff02bd4fe9221ee), I was expecting to see the URL in the metadata, however I can only see a hashed set of input data.

I believe that it is possibly because I am looking at the transaction, rather than the underlying contract, but I cannot figure out how to view the original ERC721 contract from the Etherscan page?  All roads seem to lead to this page which I believe is the main Opensea contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to get the metadata? I have the same question.

Comment: @stochasticcrap no!

Answer (score 3):

There may be a way to retrieve the metadata through Etherscan but because of the broadness of the space of possible Ethereum contracts (effectively infinite), Etherscan really only provides the most raw representation of contracts/tokens/transactions/etc. either as the EVM bytecode or the source code of the contract. Also it looks like the contract for the linked NFT is actually a [ERC-1155](https://enjin.io/erc-1155) rather than a ERC721 contract.

[image]

For Opensea contracts, by far the easiest and most reliable way to get any information is to use their API (which they provide a convenient browser explorer for): https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-a-single-asset

[image: Opensea API explorer]

It looks like for the NFT you linked the relevant image urls are:

```json
{ 
  ...,
  "image_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YNu5EBZXJQKIaynTrm6M1QeJwJaGkmLVYZ-4DmfGcySEuV-SHM9B0xqdDR5ij6D9yiPUgdH7rGSTfTGjgURoaMHLSr5AG9-MIVCk3g",
  "image_preview_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YNu5EBZXJQKIaynTrm6M1QeJwJaGkmLVYZ-4DmfGcySEuV-SHM9B0xqdDR5ij6D9yiPUgdH7rGSTfTGjgURoaMHLSr5AG9-MIVCk3g=s250",
  "image_thumbnail_url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YNu5EBZXJQKIaynTrm6M1QeJwJaGkmLVYZ-4DmfGcySEuV-SHM9B0xqdDR5ij6D9yiPUgdH7rGSTfTGjgURoaMHLSr5AG9-MIVCk3g=s128",
  ...
}
```